# Integrate a percentage equation

Tags: integration

I hope this is a simple question. How do I integrate the following equation?

$$
y = \frac{dx}{x}
$$

I can integrate the right hand side, but am lost as to what to do with the left. Is this even possible?

Comment: this $y$ does not appear to be a well defined function of $x$ if this is what is intended: normally dx is just a dummy variable.

Comment: That's not a valid equation, and the equality makes no math sense as written. Trace back where it comes from, and what it should have been, instead.

Comment: Ok, it's from economics; dx is the change in price and y is the interest rate. I'm just trying to find out the real meaning of the relationship between the change in price, price and the interest rate.

Comment: This equation is wrong, it should be$dx/dt=y*x$ where y is the annualised interested rate. Otherwise this equation makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct equation is $\frac{dx}{dt}=xy$ where y is the interest rate. Otherwise, your original equation makes instaneous jump of price possible at each time instant, which contradicts the definition of differentiable function.

To solve it one might use separation of variable:
$$\frac{dx}{x}=ydt$$ and the solution is 
$$x(t)=e^{yt}$$ with y is the time continuously compound interest rate

Comment: Great, thanks very much for the insight. I realise I missed off the time dependence.